# Asp.net core MVC and JQuery submit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this code(JQuery) in my View:

```
 $("form").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = this;
                var link = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")';
                var args = {
                    MyFVal: MyFVal.val(),
                    MySVal: MySVal.val()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: link,
                    data: args,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.acces);
                        if (data.acces) {
                            AllEnable();
                            form.submit();
                        }
                        else {
                            alert(data.erromessage);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error. Kontaktujte správce.");
                    }
                });
            });
```

When I gets submitted then I have this `if` in my save action.

```
if (Request.Form.ContainsKey("Insert"))
{
    // do code that is supposed to run
}
else if (Request.Form.ContainsKey("Edit"))
{
    // do another code
}
```

My problem is that because I submitted form by JQuery this `if` and `elseif` never gets executed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your form submit first creates a get request and then if it succeeds it follows up with actually submitting the form? So, are you sure the second part is getting triggered? You might need to show both actions (the one for the get and the one for actual form post)

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is getting executed. I had alert before it was submitted and after it was submitted and all parts were triggred until this if started then it went arounf if statement. So excecute -> alert before submit (succes) -> Console.Writeline in my IActionResult (sucess) -> If statement (did not get exucuted) -> after if statement Console.Writeline(sucess)

Comment: you are never setting those values, in the ajax payload, that you expect in the if-else for what i can tell from this request

Comment: Do you mean that if and elseif never gets executed after the form is submitted from the success function of ajax? If so ,I program a demo to test ,and the `if` gets executed well, please post the complete code of form and the actions that  pinkfloydx33  mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to pass value for your requirements in Action condition. See **operationType** sample parameter

```
    var obj = {
        UniqueId: modelUniqueId.val(),
        Name: modelName.val(),
        operationType: $("[name=operationType]").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/hrms/Class/Index',
        data: obj,
        success: function (result) {

            if (result.success == true) {
                createAndProcessPageAlert("success", result.message);
            }
            else {
                createAndProcessPageAlert("error", result.message);
            }
```

And in your Controller \ Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index(string operationType, ClassModel model)
    {
        var result = new HttpResponseModel<ClassModel>();
        var user = Request.GetUserProfile();

        if (operationType == "add")
```